# Instantiation issue of generic Interface inherited by abstract class

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics, interface, abstract

I am trying to design an application that can handle/use multiple databases and I thought it would be a good idea to encapsulate everything under Interfaces but it seems I have stumbled on the very first method
My interface is :

```
interface IConnect<T>
    {
        T dbConnection(String dbConnectionString);
    }
```

My Abstract Class is :

```
  abstract class SqliteConnect :Iconnect<SQLiteConnection>
    {
        public abstract SQLiteConnection dbConnection(String dbConnectionString);
    }
```

The Concrete implementation is :

```
  class SQLiteSpecialConnect:SqliteConnect
    {
        public override SQLiteConnection dbConnection(String fileToConnect)
        {
            return new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + fileToConnect);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to instantiate it I get

```
Iconnect<SQLiteConnection> sqliteConObj= new SQLiteSpecialConnect().dbConnection("SomeConnectionString");
```

`cannot implicitly convert type System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection to Iconnect<System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection>`

So can I use this implementation or is a no go?

Comment: What is "new SQLiteSpecialConnect:SqliteConnect()"? Shouldn't it just be "new SQLiteSpecialConnect()"? At first glance everything else looks fine.

Comment: bad copy paste...

Comment: Yeah, well of course `SQLiteConnection != Iconnect<SQLiteConnection>`... -- Use `Iconnect<SQLiteConnection> sqliteConObj= new SQLiteSpecialConnect()` and then `sqliteConObj.dbConnection("SomeConnectionString")`

Comment: A Constraint in your interface could also be useful, if you don't want to use it with anything else than DbConnection: `where T:DbConnection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
IConnect<SQLiteConnection> sqliteConObj = new SQLiteSpecialConnect();
SQLiteConnection connection = sqliteConObj.dbConnection("SomeConnectionString");
```

The problem is you're calling the method instantly so the return type is SQLiteConnection

Comment: @John - if it does, you might want to consider accepting this answer.